# how to use nginx proxy redirect for multiple apps?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have an nginx server running a reverse proxy to a odoo web server.

i need to add a redirect eg. https://webserverURL.com/redirect to https://webserverURL.com:8088/.

Is this possible and how could i do it.

Current config file.

```
server {
  listen 8088;
  server_name ipAddr;
  root /var/www/phpmyadmin/;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

}
```

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name webserverURL;
 
  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;

  # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  # SSL parameters
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/webserverURL/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/webserverURL/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/webserverURL/chain.pem;
  include snippets/ssl.conf;
  include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

  # log
  access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

  # Redirect websocket requests to odoo gevent port
  location /websocket {
    proxy_pass http://odoochat;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
  }
```

i have tried.

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://ipAddr:8088/$1 permanent;
  }
```

but this redirects to ipAddr not ipAddr:8088

Comment: Hi, try this : ```location /redirect { return 301  http://webserverURL.com:8088$request_uri; }```